# Toshiba Satellite P755-S5269 keyboard backlight doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, backlight

I'm new to Ubuntu and I have a problem with the keyboard backlight on my laptop. I was looking for solutions on the web but unfortunately I could not find anything specific.

- My laptop model is Toshiba Satellite P755-S5269.
- In the BIOS keyboard backlight is set to ON.

Does anyone have this model laptop and managed to solve this problem?

---

Eco mode if off, as well as the BIOS setting for the backlight is ON. I just tried Fn+Z but it still doesn't work. I haven't tried the media key for illumination because I don't know where's the media key for illumination? My configuration file /etc/default/grub looks after modification as follows -> http://pastebin.com/wx0rBug1

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the keys:

```
acpi_osi=linux
acpi_backlight=vendor
```

to the grub linux line at the "quiet splash" location.
If that works, edit them into the /etc/default/grub file on the
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line (when it works after typing it in at the grub prompt):
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

---

Make sure eco mode if off as well as the BIOS setting for backlight is ON.  Try the media key for illumination (above function keys if present) , and also try the key shortcut Fn Z
Hope that helps.

Comment: I added to the file these two lines turned off and turned on my computer but it didn't work.

Comment: Eco mode if off, as well as the BIOS setting for the backlight is ON. I just tried Fn+Z but it still doesn't work. I haven't tried the media key for illumination because I don't know where's the media key for illumination? My configuration file /etc/default/grub looks after modification as follows -> http://pastebin.com/wx0rBug1

Comment: I fixed a bug in the file grub and still no result: (